# Insert/upload image to tinyMCE 4.X

Tags: javascript, php, file, tinymce

I want to add feature to my tinyMCE 4.X. It is file uploader. I'm trying to do it many ways, but no one worked.  I'm using this code:

```
 tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea[name=obsah], textarea[name=perex]",
        theme: "modern",
        paste_data_images: true,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_title: true,
        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_upload_url: '/admin',
        file_picker_types: 'image',
        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];


                var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
                blobCache.add(blobInfo);


                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
            };

            input.click();
        },


    });
```

After I choose the image, it shows in the area, that is OK, but when I click submit, $_POST and $_FILES are empty and console is talking about error in JSON unexpected error. Can you help me please? How to send multiple images ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to upload image using tinyMCE 4.x as suggested by its documentation. 
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    var xhr, formData;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', 'postAcceptor.php');

    xhr.onload = function() {
      var json;

      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
        return;
      }

      json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
        failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
        return;
      }

      success(json.location);
    };

    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

    xhr.send(formData);
  }
});
```

To use this code you just need to create postAcceptor.php file pn your server. Here is the link of postAcceptor.php
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/

```
<?php
  /*******************************************************
   * Only these origins will be allowed to upload images *
   ******************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $imageFolder = "images/";

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
      if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
      }
    }

    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Im using MVC, can you please help me how to handle it ? something like 
if(isset($_POST['something'])){} ?

Comment: Just create a file "postAcceptor.php" and give its path in your tinymce options.
 xhr.open('POST', 'postAcceptor.php')
After that change your domain name in postAcceptor.php file
$accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");
And change path of that folder where you want to upload your image.
$imageFolder = "images/";